# Get some values across grid AG Grid React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, ag-grid

I am trying to get the difference between two aggregated values on the grid. For example, in the above table, I am trying to find the difference between the avg(age) and roundedAvg(age) for each country group and add it to a new column. e.g. I would have an additional column after roundedAvg(age) which would display (26.56578947 - 26.565) for Croatia, (27.0313588885017 - 27.03) for France etc.

hope this makes some sense [image]

Comment: and what is your question?

Comment: How do i take these values from the aggregation of both columns (26.565789 and 26.56) and create a new column with the difference between them (26.565789 - 26.56)?

Comment: this is easily achievable in AG Grid, but it would be easier to answer your question if you provided a stackblitz/plunker example of your problem.